# Problem about algebraic structure of $\cos\frac{2kπ}{23}$

Tags: group-theory, trigonometry, galois-theory

### Motivation

I calculated the radical expression of $\cos\dfrac{2kπ}{23}$, but I encountered some problems when extending to $\cos\dfrac{2kπ}{47}$.

One step in my calculation process is too computationally intensive.

I hope to find some mathematical methods to reduce the computational complexity.

---

### My Steps

Consider

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{11}\left(22\cos\frac{2 k π i}{23}+1\right)=0
$$

Equivalent to solving the equation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x^{11}}{23}
&=55 x^9+33 x^8-25146 x^7-25564 x^6+4986058 x^5+5978445 x^4\\&-398587728 x^3-426851414 x^2+8767235268 x+4452145237
\end{aligned}
$$

Its 11 roots $x_i$ can be obtained by combining the 10 roots $r_i$ of the resolvent.

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{10}+23^{55}&
=2300783⋅23x^9
+2300783⋅23^{45}x\\&
-89208309334⋅23^3x^8
-89208309334⋅23^{36}x^2\\&
+200684695229998⋅23^6x^7
+200684695229998⋅23^{28}x^3\\&
-8686635837127304⋅23^{10}x^6
-8686635837127304⋅23^{21}x^4\\&
-60954221740648059⋅23^{15}x^5\\&
\end{aligned}
$$

Let

$$
\begin{aligned}
ω&= e^{2πi/11}\\
ω^n&=ω^{n\bmod 11}
\end{aligned}
$$

Due to the properties of cyclic groups, the roots of the presolution can be written as $R = M_{\text{inner}}⋅Z$ where $z_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $m_{i,j} = ω^{i j \bmod 11}$

After numerical guessing and symbolic check, we can get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1\\r_2\\r_3\\r_4\\
r_5\\r_6\\r_7\\r_8\\
r_9\\r_{10}\\
\end{bmatrix}=
23\begin{bmatrix}
1 & ω & ω^2 & ω^3 & ω^4 & ω^5 & ω^6 & ω^7 & ω^8 & ω^9 \\
1 & ω^2 & ω^4 & ω^6 & ω^8 & ω^{10} & ω & ω^3 & ω^5 & ω^7 \\
1 & ω^3 & ω^6 & ω^9 & ω & ω^4 & ω^7 & ω^{10} & ω^2 & ω^5 \\
1 & ω^4 & ω^8 & ω & ω^5 & ω^9 & ω^2 & ω^6 & ω^{10} & ω^3 \\
1 & ω^5 & ω^{10} & ω^4 & ω^9 & ω^3 & ω^8 & ω^2 & ω^7 & ω \\
1 & ω^6 & ω & ω^7 & ω^2 & ω^8 & ω^3 & ω^9 & ω^4 & ω^{10} \\
1 & ω^7 & ω^3 & ω^{10} & ω^6 & ω^2 & ω^9 & ω^5 & ω & ω^8 \\
1 & ω^8 & ω^5 & ω^2 & ω^{10} & ω^7 & ω^4 & ω & ω^9 & ω^6 \\
1 & ω^9 & ω^7 & ω^5 & ω^3 & ω & ω^{10} & ω^8 & ω^6 & ω^4 \\
1 & ω^{10} & ω^9 & ω^8 & ω^7 & ω^6 & ω^5 & ω^4 & ω^3 & ω^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
384812 \\188298 \\-625515 \\-78859 \\
740707 \\84370 \\834405 \\98208 \\
361900 \\-56177 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Likewise, $X=M_{\text{outer}}⋅\sqrt[11]{R}$

After numerical guessing and symbolic check, we can get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\
x_6\\x_7\\x_8\\x_9\\x_{10}\\
x_{11}\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
ω^3 & ω & ω^2 & ω^8 & 1 & 1 & ω^3 & ω^9 & ω^{10} & ω^8 \\
ω & ω^8 & ω^7 & 1 & ω & ω^{10} & 1 & ω^4 & ω^3 & ω^{10} \\
ω^9 & ω^2 & ω^9 & ω^{10} & ω^8 & ω^3 & ω & ω^2 & ω^9 & ω^2 \\
ω^{10} & ω^4 & ω & ω^3 & ω^2 & ω^9 & ω^8 & ω^{10} & ω^7 & ω \\
ω^2 & ω^{10} & ω^{10} & ω^4 & ω^6 & ω^5 & ω^7 & ω & ω & ω^9 \\
ω^7 & ω^9 & ω^3 & ω^2 & ω^9 & ω^2 & ω^9 & ω^8 & ω^2 & ω^4 \\
ω^6 & ω^7 & 1 & ω^9 & ω^4 & ω^7 & ω^2 & 1 & ω^4 & ω^5 \\
ω^8 & 1 & ω^6 & ω^6 & ω^3 & ω^8 & ω^5 & ω^5 & 1 & ω^3 \\
ω^4 & ω^3 & ω^5 & ω & ω^5 & ω^6 & ω^{10} & ω^6 & ω^8 & ω^7 \\
1 & ω^6 & ω^4 & ω^7 & ω^7 & ω^4 & ω^4 & ω^7 & ω^5 & 1 \\
ω^5 & ω^5 & ω^8 & ω^5 & ω^{10} & ω & ω^6 & ω^3 & ω^6 & ω^6 \\
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt[11]{r_1} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_2} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_3} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_4} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_5} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_6} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_7} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_8} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_9} \\
\sqrt[11]{r_{10}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And finally

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos\left(\frac{2kπ}{23}\right) = \frac{1}{22}\left(x_k-1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

### Question

During my calculation, $M_{\text{outer}}$ was obtained by exhaustiveness.

The computer took about two days to get this result, and the time required to calculate $n = 47$ would be unacceptable.

$$
M = ω\,\verb+^+\,\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 9 & 10 & 8 \\
 1 & 8 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 10 & 0 & 4 & 3 & 10 \\
 9 & 2 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 9 & 2 \\
 10 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 9 & 8 & 10 & 7 & 1 \\
 2 & 10 & 10 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 9 \\
 7 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 9 & 8 & 2 & 4 \\
 6 & 7 & 0 & 9 & 4 & 7 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 5 \\
 8 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 3 \\
 4 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 10 & 6 & 8 & 7 \\
 0 & 6 & 4 & 7 & 7 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 0 \\
 5 & 5 & 8 & 5 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Structurally, the coefficients constitute a cycle.

Can $M_{\text{outer}}$ be derived directly from the point of view of group theory?

---

#### Update to commits

The solution of $p = 17$ doesn't help much because the highest expansion is only quadratic expansion, while $p = 23$ is up to 11st expansions, $p=47$ is up to 23rd expansions, and $p=59$ is up to 29th expansions.

Comment: wow.  Methodology in modern terms in http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf   Many examples, including yours   in Reuschle(1875)  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tafeln_complexer_Primzahlen/wt7lgfeYqMQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&pg=PR1&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Comment: especially pages 30 and 73.  Note that Reuschle  is giving a polynomial for $2 \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{p} \right)$    He does denominators that are prime powers pages 173-192.    $n=63$   is quite interesting, pages 285-304

Comment: I guess I did not include it, Cox shows how Gauss came up with radicals for $17$  in chapter 10.

Comment: The classical algebraic number theory methods of my little essay https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/kummer_eis.pdf  already do convert some nasty computations to human-accessible ones, so should enlarge the range of machine-accessible computations. Should not be hard to implement, though I've not done so.

Comment: The question phrased currently is quite recondite. You might want to elaborate more on your definitions of $x, r_i, M_{\text{outer}}$ and $M_{\text{inner}}$. With respect to which subgroup of the Galois group are you taking the resolvent?